# in hive, how to choose A if A is not null, otherwise choose B. Both A and B are field inside a json column

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, data-science

I have a hive table where there are two columns. The first column is named **user_id** and second is named **event** where the data is in JSON format. 
An example of the table will looke like:

```
user_id, event
1231321, {"ts":1554254647,"items":[{"id":12342,"label1":null,"lable2":a},{"id":2,"label1":"c","lable2":"d"}]}
2131232, {"ts":1524254647,"items":[{"id":12433,"label1":null,"lable2":null},{"id":2,"label1":"c","lable2":"d"}]}
```

How to write a query to get user_id and the label(label1 if lable1 is available, otherwise lable2). 
Using above example, the query result will be:

```
user_id, lables
1231321, [c,a]
2131232, [c,d]
```

Comment: In the first json label2=a, why c is taken as a first element? The logic is not fully described

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how json file works.
But, **coalesce** or **NVL**  is the function that can fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

SQL should be

select case when  get_json_object(json_column,'$.items.label1[0]') is null then get_json_object(json_column,'$.items.lable2[0]') else   get_json_object(json_column,'$.items.label1[0]')  end as test_data;

```
select case when  get_json_object('{"ts":1554254647,"items":[{"id":12342,"label1":null,"lable2":"a"},{"id":2,"label1":"c","lable2":"d"}]}','$.items.label1\[0]') is null then get_json_object('{"ts":1554254647,"items":[{"id":12342,"label1":null,"lable2":"a"},{"id":2,"label1":"c","lable2":"d"}]}','$.items.lable2\[0]') else   get_json_object('{"ts":1554254647,"items":[{"id":12342,"label1":null,"lable2":"a"},{"id":2,"label1":"c","lable2":"d"}]}','$.items.label1\[0]')  end as test_data;
```

+------------+--+

| test_data  |

+------------+--+

| c          |

+------------+--+